# How to disable button after button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button using onclick return confirm ... I wish when the confirm submitted... the second time to click the button it will pop up alert message to inform the user button only can click once time.

SO far , I have already try the one function but not working.

```
$("#once").one("click", function() {
  alert('this only happens once');
});
```

The following code is my button

```
<input type="submit" id="once" class="button" style="width:100px;" onclick="return  
confirm('Are you sure you want <?php  echo $show_venue['venue'];?>  be your party venue 
 ?');"  value="CHOOSE" name="choose_venue">
```

Comment: First, `.one("click"` -> `.on("click"`

Comment: @blex sorry i dont get what you mean ... can you be more specific ?

Comment: Try with.attr('disable','disable'); to disable your button click

Comment: @blex It's not a typo, `one()` is a valid jQuery method used to attach a handler to a single instance of an event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, I was not aware of that, thank you, I learned something!

Answer (score 3):

You're not disabling the button after the click.

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Here's a fiddle with the code you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/UT79m/6/

Comment: This will return the property value, not change it. Should be `prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @BenFortune no problemo. You're right about the above code using a getter though.

Comment: guys it still not working ... i think might be after button click the page will run the form action ... how can I avoid the refresh

Comment: @user3652484 Try the fiddle now. Stopped the default action of the event firing. It should stop the form being submit.

Comment: @RichFlavell still the same because the return confirm... if return to true the button actually giving permission to run a `PHP` ... then the page action to current page ... therefore the javascript are not working

Comment: @user3652484 Ahh I see! Try the latest fiddle. You might want to re-add your PHP code back into it.

Answer (score -2):

You could add a class to set a 'selected' state after the first click:

```
$("#once").on("click", function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
       return;
   alert('this only happens once');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```